# Can an attacker flip bits of a signature to create DoS?

Tags: attacks, digital-signature, denial-of-service

Assume two parties communicating. A sends a message to B signed with its private key. B received the message and verify it using the public key of A. Can an attacker launch a DoS attack by flipping bits in the signature hence preventing B from authenticating A since the Public key of A no longer corresponds to the signature?

Comment: Why flip bits? If you make the question more general, you have your answer: "if the signature is corrupted, can that prevent verification of the signature?" and the answer is "of course".

Comment: If you are able to intercept the communication (which you need to flip the bit) you could also simply block the delivery of the message.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

That would require an attacker to be able to intercept the messages exchanged between A and B, modify them and send the modified messages to their initial destinations (i.e. conduct a [mitm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attack).

Comment: Or any other corruption in the transmission.

Comment: I'm not talking about intentional interference, Simple corruption during transmission can accomplish the same thing. So, yes, you can intentionally corrupt the message, or corruption can happen at any point during the process that would accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @schroeder ah, now it makes sense, thanks. My answer was refering specifically to the OP's question (targeting the signature), but you've got a point, yes.